# Heisenberg group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

[image]I want to determine the board of the of the disk $D=\{z=(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C^2}:|z|^2=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2 <1   \}$.

Is it the Heisenberg group i,e., $\delta D=\mathbb{H^2}$?

Answer (score 3):

The highlighted sentence is misleading, if not outright false. The boundary of the unit ball in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ is the sphere $\mathbb S^{2n+1}$, which is compact; while the Heisenberg group $H^n$ is not, so you cannot identify the Heisenberg group with the boundary of the ball, either as Lie groups or as manifolds.

I suspect that what the author had in mind was one or both of the following:

1. Both the $(2n+1)$-sphere and the Heisenberg group are [CR manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR_manifold), which are the abstract models of boundaries of domains in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. The sphere obtains its CR structure as the boundary of the ball $\mathbb B^{n+1}$, while the Heisenberg group inherits its as the boundary of the ***Siegel domain*** $\mathscr D^{n+1} = \{(z^1,\dots,z^n,w): \operatorname{Im} w > |z|^2\}$. The ball and the Siegel domain are biholomorphic via the $(n+1)$-dimensional ***Cayley transform***, which is the map $K\colon \mathbb B^{n+1}\to \mathscr D^{n+1}$ given by
   $$
   K(\zeta^1,\dots,\zeta^{n+1}) = \left(
   \frac{\zeta^1}{1+\zeta^{n+1}},\dots, \frac{\zeta^n}{1+\zeta^{n+1}},
   i\frac{1-\zeta^{n+1}}{1+\zeta^{n+1}}\right).
   $$
   This map extends smoothly to a diffeomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb B^{n+1}}\smallsetminus \{(0,\dots,0,-1)\}$ to $\overline{\mathscr D^{n+1}}$, and then restricts to a CR diffeomorphism from the sphere minus a point to the Heisenberg group. For more about this, see sections 3 and 4 in [my paper with David Jerison](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214440849) on the CR Yamabe problem.
2. As Dietrich Burde noted, the group structure on $H^n$ can be realized by identifying $H^n$ with the subgroup $G$ of the biholomorphism group of $\mathscr D^{n+1}$ consisting of affine maps. These biholomorphisms extend smoothly to $\overline {\mathscr D^{n+1}}$, and $G$ acts simply transitively on $\partial \mathscr D^{n+1} \approx H^n$, so the map from $G$ to $H^n$ given by $g\mapsto g\cdot(0,\dots,0)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your exellent detail

Comment: Another question:   we have $\partial \mathscr D^{n+1}$  corresponds via  the Cayley transform  to the boundary $|w|=1$ of the unit ball, expect the southe pole $(0,\dots,0,-1)$. Hence  can we say that $H^n\approx$ corresponds to the boundary $|w|=1$ of the unit ball, expect the southe pole $(0,\dots,0,-1)$.

Comment: @FadilKikawi: Yes, provided you interpret "corresponds" in the sense of "CR diffeomorphic." But the boundary of the ball minus a point doesn't have an obvious group structure, so that correspondence doesn't account for the group structure.

Comment: Another question:  I know the expression of the dilatations and the rotation on  the Heisenberg group. But what is the  explicit expression of the translation on the  Heisenberg group.

Comment: @FadilKikawi: Do you know the group structure of the Heisenberg group? They're just left multiplication by fixed elements of the group.

Comment: I know the group structure of the Heisenberg group $\mathbb{H^n}$, this group is the set $\mathbb{C^n}\times \mathbb{R}$ with the multiplication law $$ [\xi,t].[\eta,s]=[\xi+\eta,t+s+2Im(\xi.\overline(\eta)]  $$. We know that, $\partial \mathscr D^{n+1}=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C^n}\times\mathbb{C}:Im(w)=|z|^2\}$. How to prove that     $\partial \mathscr D^{n+1}$ is invariant under the translations (for the dilatations and rotations, I don't have any problem)

Comment: The translation on the $\partial \mathscr D^{n+1}=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C^n}\times\mathbb{C}:Im(w)=|z|^2\}$ is defined by:$ T_{(z,w)}[(z',w')]=(z+z',w+w'+2iz\overline{z'})$. So  can show that $\partial \mathscr D^{n+1}$ is invariant under $T_{(z,w)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of the unit ball cannot be isomorphic to the Heisenberg Lie group.
For the correct definition of the Heisenberg group in this context
see section 1.4 [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=ljcOSMK7t0EC&pg=PA527&lpg=PA527&dq=heisenberg+group+as+boundary+of+unit+ball+in+several+complex+variables&source=bl&ots=a5WGQeVmPt&sig=PG1rlwJIxRrYkeuVv0Fpl8BhW_E&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsra_ojvTSAhVG_SwKHdrvAPEQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=heisenberg%20group%20as%20boundary%20of%20unit%20ball%20in%20several%20complex%20variables&f=false). We obtain the Heisenberg group as the group of affine holomorphic bijections of $U^n$.

Comment: Please, see above